How to install an outdoor receptacle on the other side of this indoor receptacle?
I want to have access to electric on a porch, and there's an indoor receptacle right around where it would be helpful to have an outdoor one. I did some research and it seemed simple enough:

Open the indoor receptacle up to access its gang box, look for a clear path behind it, knock out another corner hole and use a long bit to drill through it and through the wall outside.

The outdoor hole is where the wire will come out, so use that to place the outdoor gang box as a template, mark it on the outdoor wall, then cut through the siding and wall with a jigsaw

Run a new jumper NM cable through the indoor hole, run it through a gang box to be installed outdoors and install that. Hook the wire up on both ends, finish up outdoor receptacle, then it's all set.


When I started that first step, I found how this DIY project is not so simple (of course). I'm looking for expert input on how my above steps need to adjust to make this work. Here are some photos of what I'm working with, followed by a description.




What I found is a metal, new-work gang box that had side straps to the stud where the door is framed out. Peaking around and behind that box, I see that when facing the interior gang box, there is NM cable vertically along both the left and right edges of the box, but cable only enters from the right corners (bottom and top, both wired to the receptacle). Looks like fiberglass insulation behind that.
The wall is too narrow for gang boxes to be back to back, and there are these vertical cables to navigate. It's hard to imagine any possibility other than those other cables going to soffit lights and a ceiling fan on the same circuit, since this is an addition with a concrete foundation and one circuit for this side of the room.
So, here's what I'm unsure about:

How should I go about drilling a hole and running a jumper cable to a new outdoor receptacle? Just find a spot that looks clear behind the metal gang box, take a drill bit for metal and drill a fresh hole through the indoor gang box?

How to cut out the outdoor part (siding, wall) without damaging cables in the wall? I had planned to use a jigsaw but have an oscillating saw which might be better to very delicately cut only as deep as needed and where I can see what I'm cutting.

Where to locate the new box and what type to use? I figure it is best to attach to the stud, so I should aim to install the new box oriented vertically(?) and above or below the old one. I'd drill a hole in the old box at an angle and height accordingly, to try and pass cable to the new box either directly above or below the old, though that does put me in line with those up-down cable runs. The only boxes I'm aware of that let me attach to the stud without opening a wider hole are smart boxes, or I could mimic those by making my own pilot holes and screw through any box into the stud at an angle.



Cut a decent sized chunk out of the interior drywall. Use that opening to figure out where the exterior box fits and how to nicely run the wires. Install the new outlet, and patch the drywall.

@JonCuster fair enough. I've only once patched drywall, years ago, and was hoping to avoid that. But more space to access and work on this would certainly help. Will see if anyone has suggestions that keep drywall patching out of this scope o work

To be fair, I have stopped doing my own drywall repairs. I got to know a professional one when we did a remodel, and they fit in small jobs as they can when work is slow. Much better job than I ever did, and quick and cheap for a few square feet.

Drywall is a pain. But a basic drywall patch (i.e., not perfect but at least a functional wall) is a lot easier than trying to deal with any extra/too large holes in siding. No time for a full answer, so I'll just mention a few things: 1 - Stick with metal boxes; 2 - Do NOT drill through boxes - metal boxes have knockouts where you install a cable clamp and thread the cable through the clamp; 3 - you must have GFCI somewhere because of outside and outside must be weather-resistant - my recommendation is (unless already GFCI protected) replace the inside receptacle with an ordinary

GFCI receptacle (so it is protected from weather) and put an ordinary, but weather-resistant, receptacle outside.

@manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact okay that all makes sense to me, thanks. I was thinking to put this whole circuit on a GFCI breaker (it's not currently), epecially since soffit lights are on this circuit, and much of this addition was DIY'd by someone who had very poor craftsmanship in some areas and nice in others. Replacing the indoor receptacle with GFCI makes sense to me, then on the cable coming out of its load side I would pigtail in the cable going outside.

As an example of the shoddy craftsmanship, I just realized the indoor receptacle has line and load cables with ground, but the grounds are only connected to the box and not the receptacle ground screw. The receptacle just has backstabs for both cables. It's also 15A receptacle and NM14/2 on a 20A breaker, added reason I may change the breaker, but that's a different story

14/2 on a 20A breaker is no good - must change to 15A breaker. Backstabs are bad but legitimate. However, grounding to the box first is correct. Grounding to the receptacle depends on the receptacle. All switches with metal yokes and all better quality receptacles (including but not limited to GFCI/receptacles) are "self-grounding" which means that when installed in a grounded metal box there is no need to connect the ground wire to the receptacle. From the looks of it, this may be an old cheap receptacle that is not self-grounding.

Thanks for confirming and clarifying @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact I will keep that breaker fix in mind to do next

So first you have to decide, “do I want my receptacle flush or do I want a surface mount receptacle.”
If it’s external it’s gonna be super easy, all you’ll need is…

1 Bell Box 1/2”
1 Weatherproof Cover
1 WP GFCI outlet
1 Two Screw Romex Connector 1/2”
1 RC 50
Romex
Screws
Silicone

You’re going to drill a pilot hole through the back of the metal box. Then take a hole saw bit that just fits over the Two Screw Connector and Cut a hole in the siding. Then from that side knock out the metal KO in the back of the indoor metal box and put an RC 50 in the hole. After that run 12/2 Romex through the hole. Tighten the Two Screw Connector around the Romex and shove it back. Secure the Bell Box to the wall with the kit (or bust some holes in the back of it). Make up your Outlet and put the cover on. Then go inside and wire nut all of your hots, grounds, and neutrals together with a pigtail out of each. Hook up your outlet and put it back together. Go outside and silicone the Bell Box.

The second option is a flush receptacle recessed back into the wall. This is the option I would do for my house, but it could be a bit more difficult.
-1 Side Screw Or Winged Cut-in Box
-WP Cover
-12/2 Romex
-1 WP GFCI outlet
From what I can tell in the picture this should work well with your studs. You’ll start by checking what side of the metal box your stud is on (I think the right side is open, which is good). You’ll use a fin tool to cut in a hole the size of an outlet box in your siding (I recommend putting the WP cover up to it to get an idea of where it will lay flat, don’t mess up lol). Go inside to your metal box and knock out either one of those metal ko’s. Put an RC50 in whichever one you knock out and run Romex through it, aiming for the hole you cut in the siding. After you can pull it out of the hole you need to run it into the back of the cut-in. Put the cut-in in the wall, and make up your WP GFCI. Go back inside and wire nut the wires in the metal box again leaving pigtails (no backstabbing). And make up that outlet. After that you can put the WP cover on outside, make sure that it’s flush against your siding. You might need to do some trimming. After that just test make sure everything works.
No need to put the WP GFCI inside, I assume the other commenters went wrong because they didn’t use WEATHERPROOF GFCI’s. I’ve put up many and never had a single issue with any of them. It will be a tight fit inside your gang able box. If you do however decide to put it inside, please tape around the GFCI so that it doesn’t contact any of the metal inside. Also if you already have a GFCI/AFCI breaker don’t worry about a GFCI outlet, just get a regular WP outlet.
Best of luck to you, if you don’t have a lot of experience with electrical make sure to turn off the breaker. If you have any questions or need any clarification I’ll try and check this post again later.

GFCI outlets tend to not last very long outside, so as mentioned in a comment by @manassehkatz-Moving 2 Codidact, I also suggest putting the GFCI inside and connect the outside outlet up as a plain non-GFCI outlet to the LOAD side of the GFCI.  This way the GFCI will be protected from outside weather, and the outside outlet will have the necessary GFCI protection.

Thanks for laying out both options. I'm going for simplicity and minimizing scope of this install, so surface-mount seems reasonable. Just to be clear on how that interfaces with the wall and siding: the RC 50 connector is what leads cable safely out of the back of the interior box, the RC 50 connector is coupled with a 1/2" two screw Romex connector, and the two screw Romex connector is coupled with the Bell box which is mounted directly onto the siding and wall with silicon around it? What if the RC 50 doesn't reach, do I connect more in series until the two screw connector reaches outside?

Also to be clear, I don't think I've used an RC 50 before. Is this what you're referring to? https://www.homedepot.com/p/Newhouse-Hardware-1-2-in-Non-Metallic-Box-Snap-in-Connectors-10-Pack-RCR50-B10/326889211
And for the two screw Romex connector, I understand you're referring to a clamp like https://www.gordonelectricsupply.com/p/M-W-474-1-2In-Metallic-Romex-Connector/6447167?utm_source=bing&utm_medium=cpc&utm_campaign=M&W&msclkid=cae25ff7c04219ce4e5139b9f814662d

The Two Screw Connectors is for the bell box because the connection is threaded. The RC50 just protects the wire from cutting on the metal box. So you just need one of each. The Romex can be ran in walls and doesn’t need to be shielded. Those are what I’m referring too, they don’t have to be joined together. And you want the two screw connector to end up inside the wall. I’ll post a picture of the end product when I get home.

IMO you don't need to do any drywall work that one of the comments in your OP suggests.  Your existing metal box is likely attached to a stud—odds on its left side.  Since the outlet is so close to the door, you can easily determine where the box is from the outside.  With siding, I like flush outlets as opposed to surface mount, so I'd cut a rectangular hole for the outlet on the outside, a few inches above the existing box.  Start your hole as close to the stud as practical, and take care to avoid cutting the existing cable.  (I like an oscillating multitool for cutting the hole.)
Once you've got a hole, you should easily be able to access the cable holes for the existing box (from the outside of the box) to be able to add a short run from there to your new box.  May need to do a little siding R&R to get the new siding box's flanges under the siding.
There are many siding boxes out there, but I like this one (used successfully before), because it includes pretty much everything in one kit: https://www.hubbell.com/taymac/en/products/p/2294585 (I get them from Amazon)


Sorry, forgot your siding isn't gray like mine.  Yours looks white, or close to it (hard to tell with all the dirt), so you'd probably want one of these: https://www.hubbell.com/taymac/en/products/outdoor-comforts-1-gang-6-in-1-weatherproof-in-use-cover-horizontalvertical-nonmetallic-white/p/2294595

This is a great answer too, I may switch which I accepted as I might go this route! One thing I don't understand is how to connect this new outlet with the door stud that the indoor outlet is attached to. All the new outlet boxes I've looked at don't really have a way to connect with the stud, unless I'm misunderstanding something.

If not connecting with the stud, I wouldn't mind the box being surface-mounted if it's reasonably sturdy. Surface mount I can understand: screwing back of the box into the siding and plywood behind it. I'd silicone across the top and sides to keep water out. I haven't wrapped my head around how that flange does much more to prevent water intrusion - I guess it adds stability at least, by locking it all in to the exterior wall at least.

Yes, as long as you have some wood sheathing behind the siding, that flanged box can be screwed pretty much anywhere.  If you're concerned about water intrusion, you can cut your house wrap and tape it over the flange before screwing it down.  Or run a bead of sealant behind before screwing it down.

As to the stud, if you look at the electrical box, it has screw holes on the side, like a Carlon new/old work box, that can be used to screw the box to a stud. https://images.thdstatic.com/productImages/6e972139-a348-4345-90d1-400e0b8b2dea/svn/carlon-boxes-brackets-b125ab-c3_600.jpg (Obviously you don't have to use those.)
